# Framework to setup a process scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, windows, batch-processing

So we have a bunch of different processes setup in code right now. We have a framework setup around this with a couple of classes that control when these pieces of code are kicked off, where they log to, which other process they depend on, etc.

The way we currently work this is that all of these processes inherit a base one that contains `parameters`, a `Validate()` method, and a `Start()` method.

I'd like to re-do this. Right now the code is very difficult to deal with. I think each process in it of itself is setup fine, but I would like to know if there are any frameworks that anyone has used to setup what is basically just a scheduler that kicks off certain processes at different times throughout the day.

Each process should have the ability to depend on another one, have its own set of parameters, a kick off time, a frequency (Daily, Ad-hoc, etc.), and the ability to log its messages and any exceptions to the UI. The reason we want to keep interdependence is because a process shouldn't run if one it depends on fails.

Anyone know of a good framework to set something like this up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Quarz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). Looking at the project page, it seem to be reasonably active. Disclaimer: personally never used it.

Comment: This is sweet. I'm going to look this over.